# TypeScript & React - Component implements interface - use as a type?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

Let's say I have the following component

```
class MyComponent extends 
React.Component<IProps, IState> implements MyInterface {...}
```

**Now I want to say that some variable is an `instance` of a `React.Component` that has `IProps, IState` and `implements MyInterface`, something like**

`myComponent: Component<IProps, IState> implements MyInterface`, but this won't work and I have no idea why.

Can somebody clarify? I'm just starting with TypeScript and can't figure this out. **What would be an alternative to that?**

---

Please note: 
`myComponent: MyComponent` is not what I'm looking for as an answer. I want to correct my misunderstanding of TypeScript instead.

Comment: What's wrong with `myComponent: MyComponent `?

Comment: Nothing, it's just that the question is intended to correct my misunderstanding instead, not to make the code work.

Comment: Well, `implements` and `extends` only work for classes and interfaces, you can't use them for variables

Answer (score 10, accepted):

TypeScript offers something that is called intersection types. This allows you to combine multiple types.

In your case it would be something like:

```
myComponent: Component<IProps, IState> & MyInterface.
```

[typescript doc](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html)

### Why this syntax?

*Notice: I don't know why TypeScript chose for this syntax, below is only my speculation about why I think they might have chosen for this syntax.*

TypeScript uses this syntax instead of the `implements` syntax most likely because it matches more closely to the union type.

```
myComponent: Component<IProps, IState> | MyInterface
```

The above type means: Object must be of type `Component<IProps, IState>` or implement the `MyInterface` interface. For TypeScript, the distinction between classes and interfaces in types is quite small. A class type is nothing more than an interface with a constructor field.

And as it may be, the `&` and `|` tokens are also used as the bitwise AND and OR operators.

Comment: amazing, thank you! Can you elaborate on why implements won't work in this case, for dummies?

Comment: @lustoykov I have added an explaination about why I think they chose for this syntax.